# VB.NET-MYSQL - como llamar a un reporte con parametro (Crystal Report)

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports

Tengo una `query` que al ejecutarla me carga los datos de forma perfecta según un `id`, ahora, necesito generar un reporte que me traiga esa `query` (filtrada con el `id`).

Luego de mucho batallar con el `odbc`, puedo acceder a la conexión desde el diseñador de `crystal report`, pero hasta ahí llego, me aparecen solo las tablas, no me deja trabajar con un procedimiento almacenado así que lo descarto, tengo que hacerlo a pura consulta, mi duda es:

**¿Cómo hago para pasar el parámetro al reporte?**

Tengo lo siguiente:

1.- El parámetro creado en el `crystalreport` (me funciona, ya que me pide el parámetro cuando ejecuto el proyecto y filtra bien).

2.- Un `form` en el cual tengo una caja de texto, es ahí donde debo ingresar el código y que llame a la ejecución del `crystalreport`.

Se que cuando presione el boton generar el formulario, este debera pasarale al crystal el valor del codigo que esta en el textbox, pero no se como hacer esto.

este es el metodo que tengo creado:

```
Public Sub generarInformeIncidencia()
    conexionMYSQL = New MySqlConnection

    conexionMYSQL.ConnectionString = ("server=localhost;User Id=soporte;database=db_incidencias_muniquel;password=123")

    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter

    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Dim fuente As New BindingSource

    Dim frm As New frmPrincipal

    'frm.txtIDRegSoporte.Text = lblIdRegistro.Text



    'Usamos un Capturador de Errores
    Try

        'Me.dgIncidenciasAsignadas.Refresh()

        conexionMYSQL.Open()

        'Dim queryDefinitiva As String = ("SELECT inc.id_incidencia, inc.id_registro_soporte, est.identificacion_estado, met.identificacion_metodo, inc.fecha_registro,niv.id_nivel,niv.identificacion_nivel, cat.identificacion_categoria, scat.identificacion_subcategoria, inc.detalle_incidencia from tbl_incidencias inc INNER JOIN  tbl_estados_incidencia est ON inc.id_estado=est.id_estado INNER JOIN  tbl_metodos_ingreso_incidencia met ON inc.id_metodo_ingreso=met.id_metodo_ingreso INNER JOIN  tbl_niveles_incidencia niv ON inc.id_nivel=niv.id_nivel INNER JOIN tbl_categoria_incidencia cat ON inc.id_categoria=cat.id_categoria INNER JOIN tbl_subcategoria_incidencia scat ON inc.id_subcategoria=scat.id_subcategoria WHERE id_registro_soporte=@id_registro_soporte")


        Dim queryDefinitiva As String = ("SELECT inc.id_incidencia, tipo.identificacion_solicitud, inc.fecha_registro, niv.identificacion_nivel, est.identificacion_estado, met.identificacion_metodo, fun.nombre_funcionario, cat.identificacion_categoria,  scat.identificacion_subcategoria, inc.detalle_incidencia, sop.nombre_funcionario FROM tbl_incidencias inc LEFT JOIN tbl_metodos_ingreso_incidencia met ON inc.id_metodo_ingreso=met.id_metodo_ingreso LEFT JOIN tbl_funcionario fun ON inc.id_registro=fun.id_registro LEFT JOIN tbl_funcionario_soporte sop ON inc.id_registro_soporte=sop.id_registro_soporte LEFT JOIN tbl_tipo_solicitud tipo ON inc.id_tipo_solicitud=tipo.id_tipo_solicitud LEFT JOIN tbl_categoria_incidencia cat ON inc.id_categoria=cat.id_categoria LEFT JOIN tbl_subcategoria_incidencia scat ON inc.id_subcategoria=scat.id_subcategoria LEFT JOIN tbl_niveles_incidencia niv ON inc.id_nivel=niv.id_nivel LEFT JOIN tbl_estados_incidencia est ON inc.id_estado=est.id_estado WHERE inc.id_incidencia=@idIncidencia")


        comando = New MySqlCommand(queryDefinitiva, conexionMYSQL)

        'comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_registro_soporte", Convert.ToInt32(lblIdRegistro.Text))

        da.SelectCommand = comando

        da.Fill(dt)

        InformeFinalIncidencia1.SetParameterValue("idIncidencia", txtId.Text)
        visorIncidencia.ReportSource = InformeFinalIncidencia1
        visorIncidencia.Show()

        conexionMYSQL.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conexionMYSQL.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Atento a sus comentarios.

Comment: Para filtrar los datos, puedes usar el `ReportDocument.SetParameterValue("nombreParametro", valorParametro);` o también puedes hacerlo con la propiedad `SelectionFormula` del Crystal Report View, algo asi: `crystalReportView1.SelectionFormula = "{TuTabla.id} = " + id;`

Comment: gracias por tu tiempo @J-Rodríguez, Y EN MI CASO que llamaria al reporte desde un boton (al hacerle click deberia pasarle el valor que halla en el textbox) de que forma se llama al reporte para que se visualize en el visor que hay en otro form?

Comment: Es sencillo, Tomas el valor del `TextBox` lo puedes pasar como parámeto al formulario que contiene el visor de crystal, luego antes de mostrar el visor `Show()`, asignas el parámetro con el ejemplo que te comenté arriba y listo, muestra tu código para explicarte mejor

Comment: @J-Rodríguez haciendo una prueba, me funciona bien, pero el tema es que el informe esta compuesto por datos de muchas tablas (por eso mi query trabaja con left join) y ahi tengo el problema...edite mi pregunta y coloque el codigo del metodo que llamo desde el boton, pero me da error "fatal encountred"...quiero utilizar una query personalizada, pero sin usar un dataset para esto, es posible?